# Зачем нужна сериализация объектов в PHP и вообще в web-разработке?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, сериализация

Всем привет! :-)
Ребят, зачем нужна сериализация? Можно примеры?
Какой-то выигрыш в скорости загрузки приложения при его использовании в следующей сессии? Если да - то за счет чего?

Comment: Сериализация кого куда где?

Comment: 1) сохранение состояния между запросами 2) кэширование  3) передача/обмен данными и т.п. вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Грубо говоря у меня есть объект юзер со множеством методов/атрибутов, которые меняются в течении сеанса. Когда завершается сеанс - зачем мне использовать serialize, когда я могу сохранить его текущие атрибуты в БД, например?

Comment: Или я делаю то же самое, что и функция сериализации? Только своим способом. То бишь изобретаю велосипед?

Comment: При передаче данных, да, кстати, удобно передавать массивы, например...

Comment: А зачем может быть нужна сериализация при кэшировании?

Comment: Когда вы сохраняете атрибуты в БД, они в любом случае сериализуются в форматы, используемые в SQL, так что вопрос ни о чём

Comment: @andreymal вопрос нормальный, только если бы сам автор понимал что это...

Answer (score 5):

Сериализация это процесс преобразования объекта (данных) в строку. Такая строка обычно сохраняется на диск, или отправляется куда-то по сети для последующей десериализации и преобразования обратно в объект.

Сериализация обычно нужна для:

1. Отправки(получения) объекта (данных) на другой сервер(сервис, компьютер). То есть объект сериализуется в строку, потом эта строка посылается куда-то по сети, потом из строки преобразуется обратно в объект и там можно с ним работать уже как с объектом.
2. Для сохранения настроек или других данных на диск для последующего извлечения и использования. Например сделать Save игры, сохранить текущее состояние программы, сохранить настройки программы.

Строка это я написал как пример, бывают разные виды сериализации, в XML, JSON, binnary (разных видов) и.т.п.

> Грубо говоря у меня есть объект юзер со множеством методов/атрибутов,
>   которые меняются в течении сеанса. Когда завершается сеанс - зачем мне
>   использовать serialize, когда я могу сохранить его текущие атрибуты в
>   БД

Так всё правильно, в случае информации по пользователю на сайте, в большинстве сценариев в базу и сохраняется и сериализация тут не нужна.

Comment: а чем запись в базу не сериализация?

Comment: Из википедии: Сериализация - процесс перевода какой-либо структуры данных в последовательность битов. То есть всё-таки упор на "строку" (поток) чем на структурное хранение в базе.

Comment: Ну и чисто по названию методов, сохранить в базу на `C#` например функция на `EF` называется `db.UpdateChanges(); db.UserConfig.Add(userConfig);` а сериализация называется `serializer.Serialize();`. Но да согласен, что с более широкой точки зрения можно и как вы написали назвать, просто это будет менее понятно и малоупотребимо.