# в каких ситуациях нужна сериализация объекта?

Tags: php, ооп, сериализация

Много раз перечитывал, как работают функции serialize и unserialize, и магические методы __sleep и __wakeup, но до меня не доходит зачем это всё нужно, в документации даётся пример, который мне ничего особо не объяснил, к сожалению. Подскажите, в каких ситуациях стоит применять это всё?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748840/223826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это для случаев, когда вы хотите работать с данными как со строкой (например, записать массив в БД).
Это подобие функции json_encode()/json_decode(). Эти функции - один из способов сериализации.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо вам!

Comment: Можете отметить решением!

Answer (score 3):

Иногда требуется получить хеш массива, например при помощи функции `md5()`, (к примеру проверить изменились ли данные в массиве или нет), но вы просто так этого не сделаете, тогда на помощь приходит `serialize()`. Пример:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);

md5($array); //Приведет к фатальной ошибке!
md5(serialize($array)); //262bbc0aa0dc62a93e350f1f7df792b9
```

Также позволяет записать массив\объект в строку, что в дальнейшем позволяет записать её в файл\базу данных\сессию и т.д, а затем извлечь при помощи `unserialize()`. Также возможно использование json_encode() - json_decode(), что даже лучше, особенно в крайних версия PHP.